# Value is definitely in the array, but it keeps returning false

Tags: php, json, function

In my `./includes/functions.php` I have the following function

```
function ck_rank($rank)
{
    $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("./includes/globals.json");
    $status = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);
    $ranks = array();
    foreach ($status as $value) { 
        array_push($ranks, $value); 
    }
    if (in_array($rank, $ranks)) { 
        echo "true";
    } else { 
        echo "false" ; 
    }
}
```

In my main.php I'm using this to check the return of that function, and if true, display a , if false, it won't show the

```
if (ck_rank($rank)) { <td>........</td> }
```

Problem is, no matter what, the function always returns false.
I'm really new at json, and I'm sure there's a better way, but any help would be greatly appreciated!  ty

Comment: Can you add your json file text in the question?

Comment: [
    {
        "ranks":"Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief"
    }
]

Comment: the $rank variable is set from a $_SESSION on login, that's returning the correct value based on the user logged in.

Comment: That's not an array of ranks, that's a single string with all the ranks joined by commas.

Comment: Your jason data is `[ { "ranks":"Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief" } ]` or `{ "ranks":"Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief" }`

Comment: I tried:
                $result = strpos($ranks, $rank);
                if ($result) { echo "true"; }
                else { echo "false"; }

which also returns false no matter what

Comment: @RohitRasela I just copied the contents of the .json file.

Comment: I have added answer which will help you with case insensitive data string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rank variable

`[ { "ranks":"Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief" } ]`

is decoded as one string

`"Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief"`

So you should first split it by comma. For example you can do it like this:

```
function ck_rank($rank)
    {
            $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("./includes/globals.json");
            // for your json [ { "ranks":"Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief" } ]
            // $ranks variable will contain array:
            // [["ranks" => "Director,Asst. Director,Captain,Lieutenant,Chief,Deputy Chief,Dep. Chief"]] 
            $status = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);
            $ranks = explode(",", $status[0]['ranks']); 
            return in_array($rank, $ranks);
    }
```

Note that we add [0] because in your json it is an object in array with field `ranks`

Comment: Thank you maxpovver and Nigel Ren. That worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your not returning anything, you are just echoing the value true or false...

```
    if ( in_array($rank, $ranks)) { echo "true" ;}
            else { echo "false" ; }
```

Should be

```
    if ( in_array($rank, $ranks)) { 
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        return false; 
    }
```

Or you could simplify it to...

```
return in_array($rank, $ranks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function ck_rank($rank)
{
    $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("./includes/globals.json");
    $status = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);

    if (empty($status[0]['ranks'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $rankData = $status[0]['ranks'];

    $rankData = explode(',', $rankData);

    $ranks = array();

    foreach ($rankData as $value) {
        array_push($ranks, strtolower(trim($value)));
    }
    if (in_array(strtolower(trim($rank)), $ranks)) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```